# ConEmu: Searching through entire buffer

Tags: search, conemu

I've recently moved to the ConEmu console and I'm loving it. Its very configurable and it has a lot of the features that I was looking for (A Mac Terminal App replacement of sorts.)

I've not been able to figure out how to search through the entire history buffer though. Theres a key called App+F which seems to search the *visible* buffer for a string, but theres nothing that lets me search through the entire 9999 lines of buffer. Does anybody know the Keyboard shortcut for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Apps</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> may search entire buffer. But update to the **latest** build first and note that you need to "Freeze console" to enable buffer search.

BTW, <kbd>Apps</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is default hotkey, you may choose any suitable.

Comment: What if you don't have an Apps key? Also how do you freeze the console?

Comment: I tried the little search box on the top right, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Little search box do searching. Really. Nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant when I tried searching for something, nothing happened. Does this have anything to do with the console program you're currently running? I was running cygwin with zsh and then ghci?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai your question fits better to project issues but not SO question. At least screenshot is required.

Answer (score 9):

For **Windows** set different hotkey since <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> is binded to Windows actions.
Here is how to set <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
[image]